# GET lists/statuses per_page returning unexpected results

Tags: twitter

I'm calling the lists/statuses method as follows, but the results are inconsistent with the per_page parameter.

`http://api.twitter.com/1/lists/statuses.xml?slug=wp1906ultras&owner_screen_name=enloes&per_page=20&page=3`

In my example above where the per_page = 20, when I get page=1 I get 11 results. When I get page=2, I get 9 results and page=3 I get 12 results. If I set per_page to 11, I believe I get 5 results for page=1.

Does this make sense to anyone? Sure doesn't to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the reasons we've recently announced that paging will be deprecated in favor of the usage of since_id and max_id is because it's difficult to guarantee accurate paging metaphors from a service that doesn't & can't organize tweets that way.

All count and per_page parameters in the API are really "up to" parameters -- you'll get no more than the amount you specify.

This blog post outlines the upcoming deprecation: https://dev.twitter.com/blog/api-housekeeping and https://dev.twitter.com/docs/working-with-timelines outlines best practices for working with timelines like these.

I recommend moving away from using the paging metaphor to the usage of since_id and max_id for better reliability and long-term viability.

Comment: thanks this is helpful and I'll make updates accordingly, but even if we remove the paging concept from the question, I don't even get **UP TO** my page_count of 20. I get 6.