# Why is the twitter list API not returning the correct number of results?

Tags: ios, twitter

I'm using the twitter List API to get tweets from a set of accounts that I've added to a list. However, I'm noticing that for some reason I'm not receiving the correct number of tweets in the response from twitter. Here is my URL

```
https://api.twitter.com/1/lists/statuses.xml?list_id=68707107&per_page=30
```

I'm clearly asking for 30 results there, however if you just type that into a web browser you'll see it does not return 30 results. Does anyone know why this is?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The per_page attribute it's an **"up to"** value. If you use the since_id you may get better results. And the pages in the api are being deprecated as you can read in the doc.
Work your solution using the since_id and max_id arguments in the api.

Check https://dev.twitter.com/docs/working-with-timelines

Check this answer: [GET lists/statuses per_page returning unexpected results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9645323/get-lists-statuses-per-page-returning-unexpected-results)

Twitter may be limiting the number of tweets in requests to 20 so you could try downloading 20 and then load the next 10 after that.

Comment: hm interesting. Thanks for the reply. So theres no simple way to return a set number of results then?

Comment: It doesn't seem very intuitive to me either. I think they just wanna limit unnecessary queries. Because it looks like almost EVERY site has a twitter feed. Hopefully you'll find a solution to this problem. Good luck!